# How to properly wire together readers and writers for PostgreSQL COPY?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to use PostgreSQL `COPY` command to import data without creating temporary files. Initial data is in a format that requires conversion so I have something like this:

```
void itemsToCsv(String filename, Writer writer) {
  /* Start processing */
  CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT)
  for(Array[String] row: processedFile) {
    printer.printRecord(row);
  }
}
```

Now here comes the problem. I was thinking about using something like this code

```
CopyManager copyMgr = (BaseConnection) conn.getCopyAPI();
Writer w = new PipedWriter();
Reader r = new PipedReader(w);
CopyIn cpin = copyMgr.copyIn("COPY items_import (id, name)FROM STDIN CSV", r);
itemsToCsv("items_in_weird_format.xml", w)
```

As far as I understand, the `copyIn` method will block, because there's nothing to read yet. Is there some clever way to wire readers and writers together without resorting to `CopyIn.writeToCopy` method?

UPD. Solved by wrapping call to `itemsToCsv` in a thread.